# Vue - Compare two objects in array and display data if there is a match

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, compare, vuejs3

I have created a data array in Vue.js to help me build details of a list of counties in the UK. As a final step, I would like to create links between related county pages based on the data I have included in the array.

I would like to loop through the main county object and compare the items in `closeby` to the county name.

Currently, my data looks something like so:

```
createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            counties: [
                {
                    county: 'Bedfordshire',
                    link: 'example.com/link',
                    districts: [
                        { authority: "Bedford" },
                        { authority: "Luton" }
                    ],
                    cities: false,
                    coastal: false,
                    flag: true,
                    closeby: [
                        { county: 'Cambridgeshire' },
                        { county: 'Hertfordshire' },
                        { county: 'Buckinghamshire' },
                        { county: "Northamptonshire" }
                    ]
                },
                ...
            ],
        }
    }
}).mount('#app')
```

The array obviously goes on like this for each county, but I have trimmed it for ease of reading

and to spit out the section related to `closeby` I have:

```
<span v-for="(neighbour, index) in county.closeby">
    <span v-if="index !== 0 && index !== county.closeby.length - 1">, </span>
    <span v-if="index == county.closeby.length - 1 && county.closeby.length > 1"> and </span>
    {{ neighbour.county }}
</span>
```

This outputs: Cambridgeshire, Hertfordshire, Buckinghamshire and Northamptonshire

What I would like to do is include the link of each county alongside the county's relevant county name eg:

Cambridgeshire (example.com/link1), Hertfordshire (example.com/link2), Buckinghamshire (example.com/link3) and Northamptonshire (example.com/link4)

How do I compare the items in `closeby` to the link for each county in `counties` to enable them to be displayed? Bearing in mind the number of items in `closeby` will vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly try to find the link in counties array:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      counties: [
          {county: 'Bedfordshire', link: 'example.com/bedfordshire', districts: [{authority: "Bedford" },{authority: "Luton"}], cities: false, coastal: false, flag: true, closeby: [{county: 'Cambridgeshire' }, { county: 'Hertfordshire' }, { county: 'Buckinghamshire' }, { county: "Northamptonshire" }]},
          {county: 'Cambridgeshire', link: 'example.com/cambridgeshire', districts: [{authority: "Bedford" },{authority: "Luton"}], cities: false, coastal: false, flag: true, closeby: [{county: 'Bedfordshire' }, { county: 'Hertfordshire' }, { county: 'Buckinghamshire' }, { county: "Northamptonshire" }]},
          {county: 'Hertfordshire', link: 'example.com/hertfordshire', districts: [{authority: "Bedford" },{authority: "Luton"}], cities: false, coastal: false, flag: true, closeby: [{county: 'Bedfordshire' }, { county: 'Cambridgeshire' }, { county: 'Buckinghamshire' }, { county: "Northamptonshire" }]},
          {county: 'Northamptonshire', link: 'example.com/northamptonshire', districts: [{authority: "Bedford" },{authority: "Luton"}], cities: false, coastal: false, flag: true, closeby: [{county: 'Bedfordshire' }, { county: 'Cambridgeshire' }, { county: 'Buckinghamshire' }, { county: "Hertfordshire" }]},
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getLink(county) {
      return this.counties.find(c => c.county.toLowerCase() === county.toLowerCase())?.link
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="(county, i) in counties" :key="i">
    <span v-for="(neighbour, index) in county.closeby" :key="index">
      <span v-if="index !== 0 && index !== county.closeby.length - 1">, </span>
      <span v-if="index == county.closeby.length - 1 && county.closeby.length > 1"> and </span>
      <a :href="getLink(neighbour.county)" :title="getLink(neighbour.county)">{{ neighbour.county }}</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked a treat. The method was the thing I was missing.